# Subscribing to BehaviorSubject after reloading the dialog component

Tags: angular, behaviorsubject

Here is the code I already have:

**device.service.ts**

```ts
import {Injectable} from '@angular/core';
import {BehaviorSubject} from 'rxjs';


@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class DeviceService {

  deviceList: any;

  private deviceListSource = new BehaviorSubject(this.deviceList);
  currentDeviceList = this.deviceListSource.asObservable();

  constructor(){}

  getDevices(): void {
    this.http.get<any>('https://........')
      .subscribe(data => {
        this.deviceListSource.next(data.data);
      }, error => console.log('Could not GET devices.'));
  }
```

And my dialog component looks like this:

**devices.component.ts**

```ts
  ngOnInit() {

      this.deviceService.getDevices();
      this.deviceService.currentDeviceList.subscribe(data => {
      console.log(data)
    });
  }
```

This works great for sharing some values between several components. When I close the dialog (which is `devices.component.ts`) and reopen it again without reloading the whole page, the `console.log(data)` command is executed as many times as I already opened/closed the dialog. So when I open the dialog it subscribes to all the values which were added by the service by `.next()` one after another. But I want the dialog only to subscribe to the last value added by the service.

As I understood this `BehaviorSubject` is exactly for this usecase. Is there something I missed? Or is there another (better) way to achieve that?

Comment: kill the subscription.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Kill your subscription once you close your dialog.

```
someSubscription: Subscription
ngOnInit() {
      this.deviceService.getDevices();
      this.someSubscription = this.deviceService.currentDeviceList.subscribe(data => {
      console.log(data)
    });
}


ngOnDestroy() {
    if (this.someSubscription) {
        this.someSubscription .unsubscribe();
    }
}
```

Comment: Ok this works great. Thank you for helping me! Just want to understand whats happening exactly. When I reopen the dialog component, there are some other subscription instances from previous dialog opeings right?

Comment: @HansZimmer Yes, thats right! your previous subscriptions stay alive if you don't kill them, when you reopen the dialog `ngOnInit()` is called and a new subscription is created.

Comment: Thank you very much! That was not really clear for me

Comment: Could you please also explain me why the first execution of console.log(data) throws 'undefined'?

Comment: @HansZimmer if it logs undefined fir the first time, then did you check with value of `this.deviceList` when you create the behavior subject, is it defined?

Comment: Yes it is, but without a value. Updated my post. I think I got it already, thank you.

Answer (score 2):

previous subscripttion still holds the stream so you need to clear it before destroying the devices component. One way to do that is:

**devices.component.ts**

```
 destroy$ = new Subject();

 ngOnInit() {
      this.deviceService.getDevices();
      this.deviceService.currentDeviceList
       .pipe(takeUntil(this.destroy$)) // takUntil from rxjs
       .subscribe(data => {
      console.log(data)
    });
  }

 ngOnDestroy(){
    this.destroy$.next();
    this.destroy$.complete(); // always call complete for guaranteed subscription removal
 }
```

Comment: Why is a `this.destroy$.complete()` needed? `this.deviceService.currentDeviceList` will stop just when `destroy$` emits a new value.

Comment: in my experience I found GC doesn't collect references immediately after next, so calling complete will ensure proper clean-up.

Comment: Okay, maybe. Haven't played much with this type of `unsubscribe()`. This is indeed very useful rather than checking existence of all subscription variables and then do an unsubscribe().